# How to evaluate data size before storage to mysql in python

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, resources, storage

here  is a  problem in my project.

I Currently use python3.6.

This  project need to use pandas to manipulate data, and then store it in the mysql database. Before storing it in the database,  need to estimate how much storage resources to store in mysql.

Can someone provide an accurate assessment plan?